# Supplier binding is not working with spring cloud stream rabbit

Tags: spring-cloud-stream, spring-rabbit

We have a source like follows and we are using spring cloud stream rabbit binder 3.0.1.RELEASE.

```java
@Component
public class Handlers {

  private EmitterProcessor<String> sourceGenerator = EmitterProcessor.create();

  public void emitData(String str){
    sourceGenerator.onNext(str);
  }

  @Bean
  public Supplier<Flux<String>> generate() {
    return () -> sourceGenerator;
  }

  @Bean
  public Function<String, String> process() {
    return str -> str.toUpperCase();
  }


}
```

application.yml

```
spring:
  profiles: dev
  cloud:
    stream:
      function:
        definition: generate;process
        bindings:
          generate-out-0: source1
          process-in-0: source1
          process-out-0: processed

        bindingServiceProperties:
          defaultBinder: local_rabbit

      binders:
        local_rabbit:
          type: rabbit
          environment:
            spring:
              rabbitmq:
                host: localhost
                port: 5672
                username: guest
                password: guest
                virtual-host: /
```

While calling `emitData` method, we are not seeing data in RabbitMQ queue. 
We also observed that consumer binding is working. That we checked by means of direct sending of messages into a consumer linked queue through RabbitMQ Admin. But supplier binding is not working.

Also, we observed that `Supplier` without `Flux` is working fine with the same `application.yml` configuration.
Are we missing any configuration here?

Even test case with TestChannelBinderConfiguration is working fine as follows.

```java
@Slf4j
@TestPropertySource(
        properties = {"spring.cloud.function.definition = generate|process"}
)
public class HandlersTest extends AbstractTest {
  @Autowired
  private OutputDestination outputDestination;

  @Test
  public void testGeneratorAndProcessor() {
      final String testStr = "test"; 
      handlers.emitData(testStr);

      Object eventObj;
      final Message<byte[]> message = outputDestination.receive(1000);

      assertNotNull(message, "processing timeout");
      eventObj = message.getPayload();

      assertEquals(new String((byte[]) eventObj), testStr.toUpperCase());
  }
}
```

Comment: How do you invoke `emitData`? To be specific, how do you get reference to `Handlers`?

Comment: Handlers are being used like normal autowired bean from other class to call `emitdata' method.

Answer (score 1):

While I appreciate you posting a project unfortunately your story continues to change and I am still not sure what is it that you want to accomplish. So this is my last response yet I'll try to be as detailed and as informative as I can, so here is what I see from your project.

1. Your configuration is faulty. The `definition` property for functions should `spring.cloud.function.definition`

. . .

```
spring:
  cloud:
    function:
       definition: generate;process;sink
```

. . .

2. Since you are using `;` I am assuming you want all 3 functions to be bound independently (no function composition) as described in [multiple binding](https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-static/spring-cloud-stream/3.0.1.RELEASE/reference/html/spring-cloud-stream.html#_multiple_functions_in_a_single_application) section.
3. The `spring.cloud.stream.function.bindings` is a property that allows you to map generated binding name to a custom binding name as described in [Function Binding Names](https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-static/spring-cloud-stream/3.0.1.RELEASE/reference/html/spring-cloud-stream.html#_functional_binding_names). It has nothing to do with the names of the actual destinations. For that we have `destination` property which is also covered in the referenced section (e.g., --spring.cloud.stream.bindings.generate-out-0.destination=source1). However if the `destination` property is not used the binding name and the destination name is assumed to be the same.
   However, consumer destination also requires group name and if not provided it generates one. So, based on your configuration your `generate-out-0` supplier is bound to `source1` *exchange*:

[image]

The input of `process-in-in` function on the other hand is bound to `source1.anonymous...` *queue*:

[image]

And as I stated earlier there is no RabbitMQ binding between `source1` *exchange* and `source1.anonymous...` *queue*, therefore messages that are sent to `source1` *exchange*  are simply dropped. By creating such binding (e.g., via Rabbit MQ console) the messages would reach the consumer.

That said, such design is very inefficient. Why do you want to *send to* and *receive from* the same destination while in the same process space (JVM)? Why abuse the network when you can simply pass by reference? So at the very least changing `definition` to spring.cloud.function.definition=generate|process|sink`.
A better solution would simply be write your code in the supplier itself

```
public void emitData(String str) {
    String uppercased = str.toUpperCase();
    sourceGenerator.onNext(uppercased);
    System.out.println("Emitted: " + str);
}
```

and be done with it.
Anyway, I would strongly suggest for you to go over our user guide specifically the [Main Concepts](https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-static/spring-cloud-stream/3.0.1.RELEASE/reference/html/spring-cloud-stream.html#_main_concepts) section and [Programming Model](https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-static/spring-cloud-stream/3.0.1.RELEASE/reference/html/spring-cloud-stream.html#_programming_model) section as I believe you have misunderstood certain core concepts, which i believe contribute to the inconsistencies in both your post and your questions.

Comment: The difference between `spring.cloud.function.definition` and `spring.cloud.stream.function.definition` is really non obvious. These are presented in the documentation both in different places but never in the same place.... But ok, we changed it. Full response is in a separate answer below.

Answer (score 0):

When you say `we are not seeing data in RabbitMQ queue. . .`. Which queue are you talking about? When using AMQP, messages are sent to `exchanges` and if such exchange is not bound to any `queue` the message is dropped, hence my question. Did you actually bind `generate-out-0` exchange to a queue?

In any event, I just tested it and all is working as expected. Here is the complete code.

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class SimpleStreamApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        ApplicationContext context = SpringApplication.run(SimpleStreamApplication.class);
        SimpleStreamApplication app = context.getBean(SimpleStreamApplication.class);
        app.emitData("Hello");
    }

    private EmitterProcessor<String> sourceGenerator = EmitterProcessor.create();

    public void emitData(String str) {
        sourceGenerator.onNext(str);
    }

    @Bean
    public Supplier<Flux<String>> generate() {
        return () -> sourceGenerator;
    }
}
```

Comment: We have a processor link to this supplier...Just added that code as well in question.
We are not getting data in the processor. When we have supplier without Flux like follows it works just fine.
```public Supplier<String> generate() { ... }```

Comment: I am not sure I follow. What do you mean by `processor link to this supplier.`? In any event, I can not reproduce what you're describing. In fact I see the opposite - a message in Rabbit queue which is bound to `generate-out-0` exchange. So perhaps you can post a complete project on github somewhere where one of us can take a look

Comment: @OlegZhurakousky, we are expecting that the configuration above
`
        bindings:
          generate-out-0: source1
          process-in-0: source1
          process-out-0: processed
`
links the supplier and the processor by `source1` queue only. And we don't have `generate-out-0` in that case. When we are specifying in the unit test `spring.cloud.function.definition = generate|process` the data transmission works fine. But when we are running it as a boot app and monitoring state of the `source1` queue at RabbitMQ Admin, nothing is coming into that queue.

Comment: You never mentioned `generate|process` before. Now (after edit) I see `generate;process` which is not the same. So, there seem to be a lot going on on your end making it confusing for a reader of this post. So as I suggested earlier, please push the reproducible sample project somewhere on github otherwise I am not sure what else can be said here. I really don't understand what question do you want to be answered.

Comment: Also, if you are indeed using function composition as `generate|process`, why do you have `generate-out-0: source1, process-in-0: source1, process-out-0: processed` instead of `generateprocess-out-0:source1`? Please look at https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-static/spring-cloud-stream/3.0.1.RELEASE/reference/html/spring-cloud-stream.html#_functional_composition section where it is decribed in details.

Comment: https://github.com/rssdev10/spring_cloud_stream_sample

We are considering that dev/production profiles are using RabbitMQ. And therefore the app should be run as `SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE=dev ./gradlew bootRun`

Unit tests doesn't use any external broker. Also, we have separate `AbstractTest` for multiple tests.

`generate|process` chain in the test is just a sample of a workflow. The supplier we are using to connect legacy part of the app. And we need to catch the processor result to be validated before sending it to a consumer. In our app the consumer drops data asynchronously into DB.

Answer (score 0):

We did some changes in the code. But the issue is still here. Flux implementation of the supplier is not working. Non flux supplier is working fine:

```java
    @Bean
    public Supplier<Flux<String>> generate_flux() {
        return () -> sourceGenerator;
    }

    @Bean
    public Supplier<Message<?>> generate_non_flux() {
        return MessageBuilder
           .withPayload("Non flux emitter: " + LocalDateTime.now().toString())::build;
    }
```

Full source is [in the same place](https://github.com/rssdev10/spring_cloud_stream_sample/blob/master/src/main/java/sample/cloud/stream/SimpleStreamApplication.java)

Also we changed [`application.yml`](https://github.com/rssdev10/spring_cloud_stream_sample/blob/master/src/main/resources/application.yml) as you suggested, and we did some experiments. Thank you for the explanation about the meaning of topics. But we also checked and can say that RabbitMQ automatically links outputs and consumers with the same destination and any specified group names. It works both for explicitly specified groups and random generated ones. This is not about a parallel processing, this is about an ability of RabbitMQ to link it.

Both `generate_flux` and `generate_non_flux` connected to the same output destination:

```
      bindings:
        generate_flux-out-0:
          destination: source
        generate_non_flux-out-0:
          destination: source
```

Now the output of the application is:

```
Consumed: NON FLUX EMITTER: 2020-01-09T13:38:49.761801
Flux emitted: 2020-01-09T13:38:51.721094
Consumed: NON FLUX EMITTER: 2020-01-09T13:38:49.761801
Flux emitted: 2020-01-09T13:38:52.725961
Consumed: NON FLUX EMITTER: 2020-01-09T13:38:49.761801
Flux emitted: 2020-01-09T13:38:53.727054
Consumed: NON FLUX EMITTER: 2020-01-09T13:38:49.761801
Flux emitted: 2020-01-09T13:38:54.727898
Consumed: NON FLUX EMITTER: 2020-01-09T13:38:49.761801
Consumed: NON FLUX EMITTER: 2020-01-09T13:38:49.761801
```

There are processed messages with `NON FLUX` but there are no flux ones.

So, non flux emitter works fine but we cannot use it to emit by request. Flux implementation for the supplier doesn't work. From that we started and we didn't do any changes in the description of the task.

Speaking about our splitting of the code to supplier, processor and sink, we are talking about different types of machines. `supplier` - it is a legacy code which is generating data. `processor` is a memory consuming part of the workflow and we want to keep it on a separate set of VMs with ability to scale it in Kubernetes. `sink` in our case is a specific machine which is storing data into a DB. At the same time, due to legacy code, we want to have common code of the application in general and don't split it into a separate applications like Apache Beam based ones.

Comment: Your Supplier (flux or otherwise) is working just fine. I've cloned your project and ran it several times. All you need to do is to create a binding between the Rabbit exchange and queue (i've mentioned it several times in my previous responses). Also, your story keeps on changing. You are now talking about independent source/processor/sink. If that is what you want, then why do you have them in a single application context? What value do you gain by such split?

Comment: Are you sure that flux based supplier is working on your side? You can see that in our output the mark `Consumed: ` is present for non flux only. If we are commenting the non flux supplier, nothing is consumed.  And we also checked that rabbitmq shows that `source` is in bind with `source.processors`

Also, we never changed the story. We started from the flux-based supplier which is not working, and just gave you full sample workflow. The sample code is just an illustration of it.

Comment: Regarding `single application context`, not sure that understand you properly. If it is about a unit testing, we want to avoid any external queues broker. And as we know correct workflow, we want to run it locally. In any case we need to use different brokers for testing, development and production.

Comment: Yes my supplier is working and I can see all 5 messages on the queue - one I set up a binding between the the exchange (where Supplier sends messages) and queue (where consumer would receive messages).

Comment: but how it is possible? `generate_flux-out-0` in the configuration is connected to same destination as `generate_non_flux-out-0`. We are using RabbitMQ with default settings and tested it on two different PCs with different OS. And you can see about that we are getting `Consumed: NON FLUX EMITTER` only without any flux generated ones..... RabbitMQ binding of the exchange and output queue we also checked.

Comment: The issue has been fixed after removing of the `spring.cloud.stream.binders.local_rabbit.environment` branch from `application.yml`. The branch which is working is `spring.rabbitmq`. For now the number of pair `Request to emit: 1: 2020-01-11T12:33:47.851941`-`Consumed: FLUX EMMITER: 1: 2020-01-11T12:33:47.851941` is correct.

Final version [is here](https://github.com/rssdev10/spring_cloud_stream_sample)